# 404 when setting headers in parameters on fetch

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, fetch-api

I'm trying to set up a GET request on my api with fetch, but when i set headers parameters request is not triggered on the server and i handle this error in console :

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:8081/user/. Response for
>   preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404

request :

```
    let response = await fetch(url,{
        headers:{
            token: token
        }
    })
```

if i remove headers parameter, request is triggered on server.

serveur is on 8081 port - 
front is on 8002 port (with webpack)

ps : It works with postman

Comment: Sounds like the issue would be more on the server than the other way around. Check what the server request and make sure the request the front end make is formatted as expected it should help identify if the issue is on the FE or BE.

Comment: it works with postman, so no

Comment: It's a CORS issue, so you have to enable CORS support on the API server (the one running on :8081).

Comment: Thanks a lot ! it was that :)